# JBoss DataGrid udp replication from one VM to another

Tags: caching, datagrid, jboss, udp, infinispan

There are two VirtualBoxes running with openSUSE on a Windows 10 host machine, each of which has a JBoss DataGrid running. `iptables` rules are disabled system-wide on both VMs. Both VM's network adapters are configured as `Bridged Adapters`.

When second instance is up, first observes it and becomes a master. The second becomes a slave.

There is a distributed cache configured on each DataGrid as following:

```
<cache-container name="clustered" default-cache="oaas-properties-cache" statistics="true">
                <transport stack="udp" cluster="oaas-cluster" lock-timeout="60000"/>
                <distributed-cache name="code-error-message-cache" mode="ASYNC" batching="false">
                    <eviction strategy="LIRS" max-entries="10000"/>
                    <expiration max-idle="${oaas.maxidle.lifespan:87400000}" lifespan="${oaas.properties.lifespan:86400000}"/>
                </distributed-cache>
</cache-container>
```

Socket bindings are also configured:

```
<socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:5}">
        <socket-binding name="management-native" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.native.port:9999}"/>
        <socket-binding name="management-http" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.http.port:9990}"/>
        <socket-binding name="management-https" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.https.port:9443}"/>
        <socket-binding name="ajp" port="8009"/>
        <socket-binding name="hotrod" interface="management" port="11222"/>
        <socket-binding name="http" port="8080"/>
        <socket-binding name="https" port="8443"/>
        <socket-binding name="jgroups-mping" port="0" multicast-address="${jboss.default.multicast.address:234.99.54.14}" multicast-port="45700"/>
        <socket-binding name="jgroups-tcp" port="7600"/>
        <socket-binding name="jgroups-tcp-fd" port="57600"/>
        <socket-binding name="jgroups-udp" port="55200" multicast-address="${jboss.default.multicast.address:234.99.54.14}" multicast-port="45688"/>
        <socket-binding name="jgroups-udp-fd" port="54200"/>
        <socket-binding name="memcached" interface="management" port="11211"/>
        <socket-binding name="modcluster" port="0" multicast-address="<A_REAL_IP_HOES_HERE>" multicast-port="23364"/>
        <socket-binding name="remoting" port="4447"/>
        <socket-binding name="txn-recovery-environment" port="4712"/>
        <socket-binding name="txn-status-manager" port="4713"/>
    </socket-binding-group>
```

According to wireshark on both VMs *udp* packages are going from one side to another and vise versa. But I can't see those packages going through a host machine in wireshark (strange, isn't it?).

Finally, checking DataGrid's rest interface I noticed that cache replication is not actually working. Putting value to master, I can not obtain it from a slave.

And finally, since slave is running, **master** periodically logs this:

```
10:26:03,839 WARN  [org.jgroups.protocols.TP$ProtocolAdapter] (INT-1,shared=udp) JGRP000031: linux-bb91/oaas-cluster: dropping unicast message to wrong destination linux-bb91/oaas-cluster
```

and **slave** logs that:

```
10:26:03,903 WARN  [org.jgroups.protocols.UDP] (TransferQueueBundler,shared=udp) JGRP000032: null: no physical address for 4d05dc4d-66ac-1943-4e97-92c6e2b471c0, dropping message
```

Can't figure out what exactly is wrong. Here are results of **iperf** utility (from slave to master and vise versa):

```
#iperf -s -u -B $MASTER_IP -i 1
bind failed: Cannot assign requested address
------------------------------------------------------------
Server listening on UDP port 5001
Binding to local address $MASTER_IP
Receiving 1470 byte datagrams
UDP buffer size:  208 KByte (default)
------------------------------------------------------------


#iperf -c $MASTER_IP -u -T 32 -t 3 -i 1
------------------------------------------------------------
Client connecting to $MASTER_IP, UDP port 5001
Sending 1470 byte datagrams
UDP buffer size:  208 KByte (default)
------------------------------------------------------------
[  3] local 10.27.11.11 port 36857 connected with 10.27.11.87 port 5001
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  3]  0.0- 1.0 sec   121 KBytes   988 Kbits/sec
[  3]  1.0- 2.0 sec   126 KBytes  1.03 Mbits/sec
[  3]  2.0- 3.0 sec   126 KBytes  1.03 Mbits/sec
[  3]  0.0- 3.0 sec   375 KBytes  1.02 Mbits/sec                                                                                   
[  3] Sent 269 datagrams                                                                                                           
read failed: Connection refused                                                                                                    
[  3] WARNING: did not receive ack of last datagram after 5 tries.
```

But, when I'm sending `nc $SLAVE_HOST 45688` from **master** machine wireshark shows incoming packages and *ack*.

Need help, please. Have even no idea where can I dig. Thank you.

**UPD**

UDP packages seems going to both sides now. When I run **iperf3** in server mode and checking it from another vm as a client result is:

```
# iperf3 -c 10.27.11.87 -u -T 32 -t 3 -i 1
32:  Connecting to host 10.27.11.87, port 5201
32:  [  4] local 10.27.11.11 port 58036 connected to 10.27.11.87 port 5201
32:  [ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth       Total Datagrams
32:  [  4]   0.00-1.00   sec   120 KBytes   983 Kbits/sec  15  
32:  [  4]   1.00-2.00   sec   128 KBytes  1.05 Mbits/sec  16  
32:  [  4]   2.00-3.00   sec   128 KBytes  1.05 Mbits/sec  16  
32:  - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
32:  [ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth       Jitter    Lost/Total Datagrams
32:  [  4]   0.00-3.00   sec   376 KBytes  1.03 Mbits/sec  2.462 ms  0/47 (0%)  
32:  [  4] Sent 47 datagrams
32:  
32:  iperf Done.
```

and server receives packages:

```
# iperf3 -s                                                         
-----------------------------------------------------------                                      
Server listening on 5201                                                                         
-----------------------------------------------------------                                      
Accepted connection from 10.27.11.11, port 50940                                                 
[  5] local 10.27.11.87 port 5201 connected to 10.27.11.11 port 58036                            
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth       Jitter    Lost/Total Datagrams             
[  5]   0.00-1.00   sec   120 KBytes   983 Kbits/sec  0.361 ms  0/15 (0%)  
[  5]   1.00-2.00   sec   128 KBytes  1.05 Mbits/sec  6.556 ms  0/16 (0%)  
[  5]   2.00-3.00   sec   128 KBytes  1.05 Mbits/sec  2.462 ms  0/16 (0%)  
[  5]   3.00-3.04   sec  0.00 Bytes  0.00 bits/sec  2.462 ms  0/0 (-nan%)  
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth       Jitter    Lost/Total Datagrams
[  5]   0.00-3.04   sec   376 KBytes  1.01 Mbits/sec  2.462 ms  0/47 (0%)  
-----------------------------------------------------------
Server listening on 5201
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Seems like problem is that JBoss can not assemble cluster.

Comment: Anytime the nodes do not cluster, the first thing is to enable TRACE logging on `org.jgroups`.  That gives you more clues than wireshark. Also, please check `netstat` to see if this is not an IPv4/v6 issue. Are all addresses IPv4?

Answer (score 0):

Last time I saw the message "no physical address for " was years ago, and it turned up being a bug in the driver of the network interface combined with actually defective hardware.

I never tried running Infinispan on VirtualBox: this is probably not tested in combination with VirtualBox's drivers; especially the UDP stack is quite sensitive, it's generally expected to be used by power users who will go in and tune the stack (change the JGroups configuration).

For example the *ip_ttl* for the UDP protocol might not be high enough for what VirtualBox means as "bridged"?

Could you try a different virtualization or container strategy?